# Swift 3: How to call "Self" as a property?

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a question about Swift 3. In Swift 3, I know that I can do this:

```
struct Movie {
    let title = String
    let rottenTomatoesRating = Double
}
```

However, let's say I create a new instance of :

```
let StarWars = Movie(title: "Star Wars", rottenTomatoesRating: 97)
```

Is there any way that I can use the variable name "Star Wars" which is the instance name, adding it/using it as the title property. I know in some programming languages, there is a "self" property. Is it even possible to do this in Swift 3?

Another example is:

```
struct Song {
    let genre: String
    let songTitle: String
    let artist: String
    let album: String
    var formattedSong: String {
        print("Now playing \(songTitle), \(-------SONG-------) by \(artist).")
    }
}
```

Would it possible to reference the instance name within the variable "formattedSong" somehow, like this:

```
let myfavoriteSong = Song.formattedSong
let lastSongIListenedTo = Song.formattedSong
```

Even if this is not the most practical example, I am wondering if this is possible to do. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Just to be clear, what you're asking for is something akin to `Movie.instances(withTitle: "Star Wars")`, which should return the `Movie` in your example?

Comment: Where is the `variable name "Star Wars"` here? It seems like a variable value.

Comment: This isn't something you should even feel the need to do.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> let StarWars = Movie(title: "Star Wars", rottenTomatoesRating: 97)
> ```
>
> Is there any way that I can use the variable name "Star Wars" which is the instance name, adding it/using it as the title property

No. Well, yes, but only in exactly the way you are doing it. A variable *name* is not something that can be magically seen and transformed into a string by the running programming.

If you want to use a string to designate the name of something, use a dictionary with a string key:

```
var d = [String:Any]()
let title = "Star Wars"
d[title] = Movie(title: title, rottenTomatoesRating: 97)
```

Comment: _"A variable name is not something that can be magically seen and transformed into a string by the running programming"_ <-- unless the variable is a member property of some type, in which case runtime introspection using `Mirror` does just this. _However_, using such a `String` representation of a property name _to access a property and set values to it_ is, indeed, madness in the context of Swift :)

Comment: @dfri but in the OP's question it's just a local variable, so your objection is irrelevant here.

Comment: It was never intended as an objection, but just a byline (hence the _"unless ..."_), as we don't really know in what context the `StarWars` property lives; OP doesn't explicitly state that it's a local variable. So I wouldn't really call the byline irrelevant :)

Comment: What I'm saying is, give your answer, fine, @dfri, but don't mar my answer with your comment as if my answer is wrong.

Comment: Again, it was never my intention to say your answer is wrong, I thought it was clear from my comment that it was just adding a special case when we could actually get a property name as a `String` (a statement that _is true_, for that case), which I believe could be valuable for OP/readers reading this answer. I'll have to blaim my non-native English if that was really so unclear and perceived as outright negative criticism from your part. As for _"marring"_ your answer: commenting on SO answers (attempting to) add information that could be valuable is, imho, the core use of comments on SO.

Comment: ... (ellipsis), I, for one, encourage comments to my own answers as they most of the time allow for my answers to be improved, or, at the very least, include additional information to the answer that might not be obvious to all readers. In this particular case, I believe a comment regarding the fact that variable names of type member properties _can_ be introspected, _is_ valuable to some readers (even if the answer have no need for updating). Meeting such comments with hostility (which I percieve, in my non-native English, your comments to somewhat contain) isn't, imho, constructive at all.

Answer (score 0):

Property *names* are naturally given (by the developer) at compile time, so there is no reason to use these names to set *values of the properties themselves* at compile time; these values could simply be entered directly.

**Proceed with caution**

For the technical discussion, you *could* implement a non-Swift native hack for this (**but shouldn't**), combining runtime introspection using `Mirror` with subclassing `NSObject`, the latter to construct a movie container which values can be set using `NSObject`'s method [setValue(_:forKeyPath:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1418139-setvalue).

```
import Foundation

class Movie: NSObject {
    var title: String
    var rottenTomatoesRating: Double
    init(title: String, rottenTomatoesRating: Double) {
        self.title = title
        self.rottenTomatoesRating = rottenTomatoesRating
    }
}

class MovieLibrary: NSObject {
    var starWars = Movie(title: "", rottenTomatoesRating: 4.6)
    var indianaJones = Movie(title: "", rottenTomatoesRating: 4.2)
    // ...

    func setTitlesToPropertyNames() {
        for case (let label as String, is Movie) in Mirror(reflecting: self).children {
            self.setValue(label, forKeyPath: label + ".title")
        }
    }
}

var library = MovieLibrary()
library.setTitlesToPropertyNames()
print(library.starWars.title)     // "starWars"
print(library.indianaJones.title) // "indianaJones"
```

Doing this is, however, slight madness.

Introspection (the `Mirror` part above, *not the* `NSObject` subclassing) could be useful, on the other hand, if you'd only like to *inspect* properties (their names and values), especially for debugging purposes.